# Forgot to include form 1042-s

Tags: united-states, non-resident, amended-tax-return, mistakes, form-1040x

I am a student on a F-1 visa (nonresident alien), working with a Teaching Assist at my University. I did my 2019 taxes using Sprintax with the information from my form W-2 and I got a refund of $609 (that what it shows the form 1040-NR-EZ I sent to IRS).

After mailing the documentation to IRS, my University sent me the form 1042-S that apparently I was supposed to use when doing my taxes, but I didn't. After updating the information from this form, now my refund is less, so I owe $85.

What I should do? I should wait for IRS to notify me that I am missing a document (I do not know if they do that) or I should fill an amendment 1040X form?

I'd appreciate any help,

Comment: Do you mean you filed the return _claiming_ a refund of $609, or you actually _received_ it? Yes, you should amend, using 1040X, but it's best if they've completed processing the original first; given this year they've extended the deadline for essentially everything to July, if you haven't received the refund I would wait until you do to avoid any possible confusion. You _can_ wait for their notice, and maybe save a little postage, but that probably won't come until fall matching season maybe Oct-Dec, which is likely to be less convenient.

Comment: Thanks for your message, Dave. No, I did not receive any money yet, I just send the forms to IRS the last week stating that my refund would be $609, but it is actually less because I missed that document 1042-S... so do you suggest I should wait for the refund and then send the amend (form 1040X) before 15th July? Thank you.

Comment: Exactly. Or if you want, use https://sa.www4.irs.gov/irfof/lang/en/irfofgetstatus.jsp . Once you either receive your refund or see it has been approved, you know they processed the original return, and then you can safely send the amended return.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good! One more question: I am reading about that form 1040X and I am not sure if I have to fill out those columns A,B and C or not. The instructions state something like To amend Form 1040NR or 1040NR-EZ, or to file the correct
return, we just need to fill the part III. I do not know if you get my point but it seems pretty confusing to fill out this 1040X form. If you have any information on how I should fill out the 1040X please let me know. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, per https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040x#idm140284808146256 for amendment of, or to or from, nonresident, you don't fill out part I or II. Just put in part III a brief explanation (maybe "failed to include 1042-S from $payor") and attach the corrected return, marked 'Amended' at the top, and [in front attach the fililng copy of the new 1042-S](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040x#idm140284779636016) (should be copy A, I think).  (Amending a _resident_ return is often more tedious -- you could legitimately rejoice at your good fortune! Okay, not all that good.)

Comment: But I want to make sure this instruction applies to all the 1040NR-EZ forms amendments (including when you do not include an income from a form like 1042-S) or only when you wrongly filed form 1040 instead of a 1040-NR and you want to fix this? I do not know if you get the point.